# Как исправить отображение текстур obj/g3dj в LibGDX Java

Tags: java, libgdx, obj

Нужно создать приложение отображающие объекты (их создаю в `Blender`).
Далее есть возможность сохранить в формате **obj** или **fbx**.

По гайдам понял, что есть два варианта:

- перевести в **G3DB/G3DJ**
- пользоваться самим **obj** форматом.

Однако **G3DB/G3DJ** просто не отображает объект. А **obj** выводит полностью белый объект без текстур.

Прошу указать в чем ошибка в использовании **G3DB/G3DJ** или сказать как показать текстуры на obj.

**Фрагмент кода mtl файла**

```json
"materials": [
    {
        "id": "Default OBJ", 
        "ambient": [ 0.050876,  0.050876,  0.050876], 
        "diffuse": [ 0.001547,  0.000055,  0.000055], 
        "emissive": [ 0.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000], 
        "opacity":  1.000000,
        "specular": [ 0.001547,  0.000055,  0.000055], 
        "shininess":  25.000000
    }, 
    {
        "id": "Material", 
        "ambient": [ 0.050876,  0.050876,  0.050876], 
        "diffuse": [ 0.051959,  0.004757,  0.157481], 
        "emissive": [ 0.008614,  0.000655,  0.027222], 
        "opacity":  1.000000,
        "specular": [ 0.051959,  0.004757,  0.157481], 
        "shininess":  15.999998
    }, 
    {
        "id": "Material.002", 
        "ambient": [ 0.050876,  0.050876,  0.050876], 
        "diffuse": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
        "emissive": [ 0.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000], 
        "opacity":  1.000000,
        "specular": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
        "shininess":  25.000000
    }, 
    {
        "id": "Material.003", 
        "ambient": [ 0.050876,  0.050876,  0.050876], 
        "diffuse": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
        "emissive": [ 0.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000], 
        "opacity":  1.000000,
        "specular": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
        "shininess":  25.000000
    }, 
    {
        "id": "Material.006", 
        "ambient": [ 0.050876,  0.050876,  0.050876], 
        "diffuse": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
        "emissive": [ 0.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000], 
        "opacity":  1.000000,
        "specular": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
        "shininess":  25.000000, 
        "textures": [
            {
                "id": "base_color_texture", 
                "filename": "thumb_l_2612.jpg", 
                "type": "DIFFUSE"
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

**Основной класс**

```java
public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter  {

    public Environment environment;
    public PerspectiveCamera cam;
    public CameraInputController camController;
    public ModelBatch modelBatch;
    public Model model;
    public ModelInstance instance;
    public AssetManager assets ;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        environment = new Environment();
        environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
        environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));

        modelBatch = new ModelBatch();

        cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        cam.position.set(5,5,5);
        cam.lookAt(0, 10, 0);
        cam.near = 1f;
        cam.far = 300f;
        cam.update();

        assets = new AssetManager();
        assets.load("fall_sleepy.obj", Model.class);
        assets.finishLoading();
        model = assets.get("fall_sleepy.obj", Model.class);
        instance = new ModelInstance(model);

        camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        camController.update();
        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        modelBatch.begin(cam);
        modelBatch.render(instance, environment);
        modelBatch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        modelBatch.dispose();
        assets.dispose() ;
    }
}
```